# HTML5 AppCache: Can somebody explain purpose of NETWORK section in manifest file?

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I have gone through html5rocks, mozilla developer doc. Those definitions are very confusing. Can anybody explain this in simple terms ?

I am not sure why do we even need NETWORK section in appcache manifest file. I think it is as good as not having entry in CACHE section.

NETWORK [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache):

> Files listed under the NETWORK: section header in the cache manifest
>   file are white-listed resources that require a connection to the
>   server. **All requests to such resources bypass the cache**, *even if the
>   user is offline*. The wildcard character * can be used once. Most sites
>   need *.

NETWORK [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/):

> Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't
>   in the cache, **otherwise the network isn't used**, *even if the user is
>   online*. You can white-list specific URLs here, or simply "*", which
>   allows all URLs. Most sites need "*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NETWORK:` are resources that *requires* the user to be online.

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

> NETWORK:
>
> Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't in the cache, otherwise the network isn't used, even if the user is online. You can white-list specific URLs here, or simply "*", which allows all URLs. Most sites need "*".

General practice is to define what resources should be cached using the `CACHE` section, and then use `NETWORK` section with `*` wildcard to default all other resources to require the user to be online.

Example:

```
 CACHE:
 # These resources will be downloaded once to be cached  on the client.
 # After they are cached, even if the user has a network connection,
 # they will not re-download these resources, but instead use their local
 # cached copies instead.

 /favicon.ico
 /index.html
 /images/banner.html

 # This section will explicitly tell the client "every other resource"
 # requires a network connection.
 NETWORK:
 *
```

So why would you explicitly tell the client that every other resource requires a network connection?

http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag#section7 Gotcha #5 will explain that.

> If you cache index.html but not cat.jpg, that image will not display on index.html even if you’re online.

And you can see their demo here: http://appcache-demo.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/without-network/